# If statement not executing when conditions are met (conditions: two variable are NULL)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm running a two variable dropdown query search but seems to be having a problem with an if-statement not executing when conditions are met. Specifically when the two dropdown list are on the default selected option with a return value of `NULL`.

Please see code below.

Code for the two dropdown lists:

```
print("<form action='patients.php' method='get'>");



// csSelection & sfSelection declaration of arrays to populate dropdown selection
$csSelection=array("","","","","");
$sfSelection=array("","","","","");
if(isset($_REQUEST['search'])) {

    if (isset($_GET['cs'])) {
            $csSelection=array("","","","","");
            $cs= $_GET['cs'];

            if ($cs=='1') {$csSelection[1]='selected';}
            else if ($cs=='2') {$csSelection[2]='selected';}
            else if ($cs=='3') {$csSelection[3]='selected';}
            else if ($cs=='4') {$csSelection[4]='selected';}
            else if ($cs=='0') {$csSelection[0]='selected';}
            //var_dump($cs);
            //var_dump($csSelection);
    }

    if (isset($_GET['sf'])) {
            $sfSelection=array("","","","","");
            $sf = $_GET['sf'];

            if ($sf=='Analyzed') {$sfSelection[1]='selected';}
            else if ($sf=='New Case') {$sfSelection[2]='selected';}
            else if ($sf=='Updated Case') {$sfSelection[3]='selected';}
            else if ($sf=='None') {$sfSelection[4]='selected';}
            else if ($sf=='0') {$sfSelection[0]='selected';}
    }
}


// Case status dropdown list
print("<select name='cs'> 
            <option ".$csSelection[0]." value=''>--Select Case Status--</option>
            <option value='1' ".$csSelection[1].">Pass</option>
            <option value='2' ".$csSelection[2].">Failed</option>
            <option value='3' ".$csSelection[3].">Pass With Error</option>
            <option value='4' ".$csSelection[4].">Indeterminate</option>
      </select>");

// Case Flag dropdown list
print("<select name='sf'>
            <option ".$sfSelection[0]." value=''>--Select Flagged Status--</option>
            <option value='Analyzed' ".$sfSelection[1].">Analyzed Case</option>
            <option value='New Case' ".$sfSelection[2].">New Case</option>
            <option value='Updated Case' ".$sfSelection[3].">Updated Case (New Images)</option>
            <option value='None' ".$sfSelection[4].">No Status Flag</option>
      </select>");

print("<input type='submit' name='search' value='Search'></form>");
```

If statements. Having problems with the `else if (($cs==NULL) && ($sf==NULL))` statement, it is not returning anything.

```
if (isset($_GET['cs']) && isset($_GET['sf']) ) {
            $cs= $_GET['cs'];
            $sf= $_GET['sf'];

            var_dump($cs);
            var_dump($sf);

            if (($sf==NULL) && ($cs!==NULL)) {
                    $sql = "SELECT patientid, sub_status_lookup.CASE_STATUS, sub_status_lookup.SUB_STATUS, count(DISTINCT caseid) as cases_count, cases.comments, date_mod, caseid, user_mod, status_flag  FROM cases, sub_status_lookup
                    Where cases.status = sub_status_lookup.SUB_ID and sub_status_lookup.STATUS_ID = '".$cs."'
                    Group By patientid, cases.status";      

            } else if (($sf!==NULL) && ($cs==NULL)) {
                    $sql = "SELECT patientid, sub_status_lookup.CASE_STATUS, sub_status_lookup.SUB_STATUS, count(DISTINCT caseid) as cases_count, cases.comments, date_mod, caseid, user_mod, status_flag  FROM cases, sub_status_lookup
                    Where cases.status = sub_status_lookup.SUB_ID and cases.status_flag = '".$sf."'
                    Group By patientid, cases.status";      
                    //var_dump($sql);
            } else if (($cs!==NULL) && ($sf!==NULL)){

                    $sql = "SELECT patientid, sub_status_lookup.CASE_STATUS, sub_status_lookup.SUB_STATUS, count(DISTINCT caseid) as cases_count, cases.comments, date_mod, caseid, user_mod, status_flag  FROM cases, sub_status_lookup
                    Where cases.status = sub_status_lookup.SUB_ID and sub_status_lookup.STATUS_ID = '".$cs."' and cases.status_flag = '".$sf."'
                    Group By patientid, cases.status";      

            } else if (($cs==NULL) && ($sf==NULL)) {
                    var_dump($sql); // This does not print out when both $cs and $sf are on the default NULL

                    $sql = "SELECT patientid, sub_status_lookup.CASE_STATUS, sub_status_lookup.SUB_STATUS, count(caseid) as cases_count, cases.comments, date_mod, caseid, user_mod, status_flag  FROM cases, sub_status_lookup
                    Where cases.status = sub_status_lookup.SUB_ID
                    Group By patientid, cases.status ";

            }
}
```

UPDATE: Thanks for the comments! I did move the last statement out of the if (isset) condition and into the else statement. However, it is still not working, I found out that instead of going to the else statement when both are NULL. It executes the first if-statement under the condition: `(($sf==NULL) && ($cs!==NULL))` the $cs and $sf values are grabbed from the URL: patients.php?cs=&sf=&search=Search. How do I remedy this?

Comment: You have SQL injection vulnerabilities by using `$_GET` values unfiltered and not using prepared statements. You should also be using `elseif` instead of `else if`.

Comment: That's a beautiful wall of code. Could you highlight the important part of it please?

Comment: or perhaps just provide a simplified test case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way your if statement is authored `(isset($_GET['cs']) && isset($_GET['sf'])` has to be true to even get to the else if statement in question.

Logically they are the inverse of one another so your final else if statement will never run. Try moving the contents of the `$cf == null && $sf == null` branch to the else clause of the outer if.

```
if (isset($_GET['cs']) && isset($_GET['sf']) ) {
            $cs= $_GET['cs'];
            $sf= $_GET['sf'];

            var_dump($cs);
            var_dump($sf);

            if (($sf==NULL) && ($cs!==NULL)) {
                    $sql = "SELECT patientid, sub_status_lookup.CASE_STATUS, sub_status_lookup.SUB_STATUS, count(DISTINCT caseid) as cases_count, cases.comments, date_mod, caseid, user_mod, status_flag  FROM cases, sub_status_lookup
                    Where cases.status = sub_status_lookup.SUB_ID and sub_status_lookup.STATUS_ID = '".$cs."'
                    Group By patientid, cases.status";      

            } else if (($sf!==NULL) && ($cs==NULL)) {
                    $sql = "SELECT patientid, sub_status_lookup.CASE_STATUS, sub_status_lookup.SUB_STATUS, count(DISTINCT caseid) as cases_count, cases.comments, date_mod, caseid, user_mod, status_flag  FROM cases, sub_status_lookup
                    Where cases.status = sub_status_lookup.SUB_ID and cases.status_flag = '".$sf."'
                    Group By patientid, cases.status";      
                    //var_dump($sql);
            } else if (($cs!==NULL) && ($sf!==NULL)){

                    $sql = "SELECT patientid, sub_status_lookup.CASE_STATUS, sub_status_lookup.SUB_STATUS, count(DISTINCT caseid) as cases_count, cases.comments, date_mod, caseid, user_mod, status_flag  FROM cases, sub_status_lookup
                    Where cases.status = sub_status_lookup.SUB_ID and sub_status_lookup.STATUS_ID = '".$cs."' and cases.status_flag = '".$sf."'
                    Group By patientid, cases.status";      

            } 
} else {
    var_dump($sql); // This does not print out when both $cs and $sf are on the default NULL

    $sql = "SELECT patientid, sub_status_lookup.CASE_STATUS, sub_status_lookup.SUB_STATUS, count(caseid) as cases_count, cases.comments, date_mod, caseid, user_mod, status_flag  FROM cases, sub_status_lookup
    Where cases.status = sub_status_lookup.SUB_ID
    Group By patientid, cases.status ";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! However, it is still not working, I found out that instead of going to the else statement when both are NULL. It executes the first if-statement under the condition: `(($sf==NULL) && ($cs!==NULL))` the $cs and $sf values are grabbed from the URL: patients.php?cs=&sf=&search=Search. How do I remedy this?